# Logstash - find length of split result inside mutate

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-configuration

I'm newbie with Logstash. Currently i'm trying to parse a log in CSV format. I need to split a field with whitespace delimiter, then i'll add new field(s) based on split result.

Here is the filter i need to create:

```
filter {
...
mutate {
    split => ["user", " "]
    if [user.length] == 2 {
        add_field => { "sourceUsername" => "%{user[0]}" }
        add_field => { "sourceAddress" => "%{user[1]}" }
    }
    else if [user.length] == 1 {
        add_field => { "sourceAddress" => "%{user[0]}" }
    }
}
...
}
```

I got error after the `if` script.
Please advice, is there any way to capture the length of split result inside mutate plugin.

Thanks,
Heri

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your code example I suppose that you are done with csv parsing and you already have a field `user` which has either a value that contains a `sourceAddress` or a value that contains a `sourceUsername sourceAddress` (separated by whitespace).

Now, there are a [lot of filters](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/filter-plugins.html) that can be used to retrieve further fields. You don't need to use the *mutate* filter to split the field. In this case, a more flexible approach would be the [grok filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-grok.html).

**Filter:**

```
grok {
    match => {
        "user" => [ 
            "%{WORD:sourceUsername} %{IP:sourceAddress}",
            "%{WORD:sourceUsername}"
            ]
    }
}
```

A field *"user" => "192.168.0.99"* would result in

`"sourceAddress" => "191.168.0.99"`.

A field *"user" => "Herry 192.168.0.99"* would result in

`"sourceUsername" => "Herry", "sourceAddress" => "191.168.0.99"`

Of course you can change `IP` to `WORD` if your sourceAddress is not an IP.